# Is there a way to pause/stop (preferabley pause) audio playback when the user disconnects the headset from the device?

Tags: android, audio

I noticed that on my smartphone that audio playback on a lot of built-in apps stop when I disconnect my headset from my phone. How do you set that programmatically or is that something standard on android devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Use Broadcast receiver. Add Intent Filter (Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG).

The intent will have the following extra values:

state - 0 for unplugged, 1 for plugged. 
name - Headset type, human readable string 
microphone - 1 if headset has a microphone, 0 otherwise

1. From the onRecive() method you can control the Audio playback.